# Can not add font to dynamic text field

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am Tring to Add Font in my dynamic text field But it just dont happens
here is the code

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.color = stringColor;

format.font="Palentino linotype";
   mysidepanel.badgeHolder.defaultbg.usernameholder.engraveUsername.setTextFormat(format);
   mysidepanel.badgeHolder.defaultbg.designationholder.engraveUserdesg.setTextFormat(format);
   mysidepanel.badgeHolder.defaultbg.usersloganholder.engraveUserslogan.setTextFormat(format);

ANd i have embeded the font Palentino linotype. may be i am not embeding the font properly if some one helps me in this i will be very gratefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set `mysidepanel.badgeHolder.defaultbg.usernameholder.engraveUsername.embedFonts = true` before setting text format. [Here is a more complete guide.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/#section2)